# Is there a better type of sensor to measure the distance instead of Ultrasonic sensors

Tags: sensors, ultrasonic-sensors

We know that the Ultrasonic sensors can't accurately measure the distance to an object that

1. is more than 3 meters away (the distance may vary on brands)
2. has it's reflective surface at a shallow angle (the angle may vary on brands)
3. is too small to reflect enough sound

[image: Ultrasonic Sensor]

Also the environmental influences such as air tempereture, air pressure, air currents, humidity, mist and types of gas cause inaccurate measurements. Which sensor should i use to get the best measurements ?

Comment: I assume the question is for indoor, wheeled robot that's trying to self locate or prevent collision. If not, can you add whether it's Indoor or outdoor ? What sort of a distance is relevant? To a wall , to grass?

Comment: This is more like a general question. I'd like to keep it that way for those who want to get informed. It can be for both indoor and outdoor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are IR sensors as well, which provide ranges up to 3-4 meters [Pololu Range Finder](https://www.pololu.com/category/79/sharp-distance-sensors). Also, we can find Laser range finders that measure up to 30m distance. But these Laser range finders are expensive in compared to ultrasonic sensors and mostly used for mapping purposes.

Comment: As far as i remember there are some environmental influences that cause inaccurate measurements for IR sensors as well, such as light. Am i wrong ? I don't have much info about the laser range finders, is there any factor that may lead inaccurate measurements ?